# How to check each form controller's type posted to action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, formcollection

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Label("WebLinkLabel")
    @Html.Editor("WebLinkTextbox")
    @Html.Label("WebEnabledLabel")
    @Html.CheckBox("WebEnabledCheckbox")
    <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
    {
       var typee = collection.GetType();   
    }

    return View();
}
```

GetType() gives me that:

```
collection.AllKeys.GetType()    
{Name = "String[]" FullName = "System.String[]"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

I would like to know like the first controller is of type Textbox, another one is Checkbox etc..

Comment: A form only posts back name/values pairs, not any information about the controls used to generate them.

Comment: You are saying only way is to inference from the value the controllers have. Like "true,flase" so it's a checkbox. But editor might have the value true, false. That's the problem

Comment: Use a view model, bind the properties of your model using strongly typed helpers, and post back the model (not `FormCollection`)

Comment: I can't see any reason that would require the controller to know what kind of GUI element created a specific value. Most probably you should improve the structure of your model.

Comment: It's a CMS. Front-end developers modify the form.